# DiscoveryClient_EMPLOYEE-SERVICE/localhost:employee-service:9090 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm running the code: https://dzone.com/articles/quick-guide-to-microservices-with-spring-boot-20-e from here and only updated **spring boot** dependency version **2.0.4.RELEASE** where code works very well, but when I updated Spring Boot version **`2.1.2.RELEASE`** where code giving errors.

**It look like `discovery-service` is not reading the config details from `config-service` and hence this is creating the below error. Is there any change in the `spring.profiles.active=native` ? It seem this config setting not working well.**

Error:

```
2019-01-19 21:34:10  WARN [employee-service,,,] Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2019-01-19 21:34:10  WARN [employee-service,,,] DiscoveryClient_EMPLOYEE-SERVICE/localhost:employee-service:9090 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:829) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
2019-01-19 21:34:10  WARN [employee-service,,,] There was a problem with the instance info replicator
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:829) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
2019-01-19 21:34:38  INFO [employee-service,,,] Disable delta property : false
2019-01-19 21:34:38  INFO [employee-service,,,] Single vip registry refresh property : null
2019-01-19 21:34:38  INFO [employee-service,,,] Force full registry fetch : false
2019-01-19 21:34:38  INFO [employee-service,,,] Application is null : false
2019-01-19 21:34:38  INFO [employee-service,,,] Registered Applications size is zero : true
2019-01-19 21:34:38  INFO [employee-service,,,] Application version is -1: true
2019-01-19 21:34:38  INFO [employee-service,,,] Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2019-01-19 21:34:40 ERROR [employee-service,,,] Request execution error
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:529) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.sendHeartBeat(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:102) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:846) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1399) [eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

[image]

**employee-service.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8090

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

logging:
  pattern: 
    console: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} %m%n"
```

**employee-service-instance2.yml**

```
server:
  port: 9090

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

logging:
  pattern: 
    console: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} %m%n"
```

**discovery-service.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8061

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

**config:**

```
pc@DESKTOP-NQ639DU MINGW64 /f/spring-cloud-howtodoinjava/microservices-eureka-cloud/Boot-2.0.4.RELEASE/sample-spring-microservices-new_2.0.4_RELEASE/config-service/src/main/resources/config (master)
$ ls -ltr
total 10
-rw-r--r-- 1 pc 197121 212 Jan 19 20:59 department-service.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 pc 197121 206 Jan 19 20:59 employee-service-instance2.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 pc 197121 212 Jan 19 20:59 employee-service.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 pc 197121 925 Jan 19 20:59 gateway-service.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 pc 197121 212 Jan 19 20:59 organization-service.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 pc 197121 486 Jan 19 20:59 proxy-service.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 pc 197121 239 Jan 19 21:23 discovery-service.yml
```

Comment: You have eureka urls pointed to port 8761 yes eureka is running on 8090

Comment: @spencergibb  - I'm not clear. I followed the same code without any changes still it gives error.

Comment: Are you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You're running discovery service on port 8061.
But according to your employee-service.yml, the eureka clients try to register to
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: **http://localhost:8761/eureka/**

Comment: That part is correct as per authors note in the post and this configuration works fine till `2.0.4.RELEASE`.